# OSX  Screenshot with C++ and CGWindow API

Tags: c++, c, macos, screenshot

I'm trying to take a screenshot on OSX with C/C++.
So far this is what I got:

```
#import <ApplicationServices/ApplicationServices.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv) {
  CGImageRef screenShot = CGWindowListCreateImage( CGRectInfinite,
      kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly, kCGNullWindowID, kCGWindowImageDefault);

  CFStringRef file = CFSTR("/Users/aduh/Desktop/lala.jpg");
  CFStringRef type = CFSTR("public.jpeg");
  CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateWithString( NULL, file, NULL );
  CGImageDestinationRef idst = CGImageDestinationCreateWithURL( urlRef, type, 1, NULL );
  CGImageDestinationAddImage( idst, screenShot, NULL );
  CGImageDestinationFinalize( idst );}
```

It compiles fine but nothing really happens. I'm probably just making a stupid mistake so if anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

As the guy above stated, this can be fixed like this, I'm also using C++ if it matters:

```
CFURLRef urlRef = CFURLCreateWithFileSystemPath( kCFAllocatorDefault, file, kCFURLPOSIXPathStyle, false );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `CFURLCreateWithString()` with `CFURLCreateWithSystemPath()`